# Open dns still detects malware activity after having scanned and removed malware

Tags: virus, malware, spyware, opendns

I'm using open dns to block unwanted sites. Everytime I go to the dashboard I always see this malware activity in all of the networks that I have in open dns. 
What do I do?I'm using avast free, spybot, and sas. And used them all to full scan the system. And they have removed the malware. But I still see this malware activity notice in open dns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenDNS blocks websites that have malware on them, not malware on your computer.  So when you see malware activity in OpenDNS that means that those sites are still bad sites that you don't want to visit, **not** that you have any malware on your computer.